# python scrapy shell exception: address "'http:" not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

Tags: python, shell, scrapy

Actually it's a sample of scrapy tutorial in **Extracting data** of [scrapy](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html). Everything goes well until the sample of scrapy shell, when I type the command in Windows cmd:

```
scrapy shell 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
```

I got an exception like

```
twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: address "'http:" not found: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed.
```

Exception in thread Thread-1 (most likely raised during interpreter shutdown):

in detail it's like:
[[image: scrapy shell exception]]
and I have searched the `stackoverflow` and find a similar problem like [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35062932/6653189)
and one answer is try another terminal,and I tried the terminal of Pycharm but it fails with the same exception.

PS: I work on windows and Python 2.7.12, Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)

I'm quite new to scrapy so any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well,it may be related to the quotation, I tried to use `"` to enclose the urls and it works, I do not know if this command differs in different OS since the original tutorial commmand code use the `'` to enclose the urls.

---

I also post this issue on the scrapy and as @kmike said, it works well with `'` on other OS like (MAC and Linux or Unix) ([github](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues/2325#issuecomment-253737415))

Comment: Simple solution that I would have probably taken hours to find... Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this question with the same error for a local .html files, I found I had to prefix the filename with the current folder and not just supply the filename.

Using

```
scrapy shell local_file.html
```

results in the error

> twisted.internet.error.DNSLookupError: DNS lookup failed: address 'local_file.htm' not found: [Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known.

however, using

```
scrapy shell ./local_file.html
```

launches the shell and loads the file.

Although the format of the file path *is* [specified in the docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html#launch-the-shell), I didn't realise it would be required (I assumed I would not have to supply `./` for a local file) but the docs do give examples to follow.

> `shell` also works for local files. This can be handy if you want to play around with a local copy of a web page. shell understands the following syntaxes for local files:
>
> **UNIX-style**
>
> `scrapy shell ./path/to/file.html`
>
> `scrapy shell ../other/path/to/file.html`
>
> `scrapy shell /absolute/path/to/file.html`
>
> **File URI**
>
> `scrapy shell file:///absolute/path/to/file.html`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and removing the single quotes around the url worked for me. I'm on windows, python 3.6

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19754367)

Comment: @loki it answered the question just fine... this solved the issue for me :/